# Random Selection of value in a dynamic dropdown list using robot framework

Tags: random, robotframework

Is it possible to randomly select a value from a dropdown list using robot framework?

My scenario is as follows:

1. I have this element with xpath of `//*[@id='companyName']`. All values here are populated upon creation of company, so all created companies are listed in that Dropdown list.
2. That element belongs to another form/page which is the creation of facility, is it possible to create a facility wherein selected company can be randomized?

Sorry for the noob question, just a newbie in robot framework :D

Comment: If you know how many companies exist, you could randomly generate a number between 0 and companies number and use the Select From List by Index keyword.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to slightly reformat your question. You can highlight code in your text by wrapping it in backticks (` -> for inline code) or by indenting it by four spaces (for code blocks).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Is that really all you're asking?

Comment: @m00am thanks for the info :)

Comment: Please do not add images of your code. Add the code! Code in images can neither be searched nor copied.